# GLGetProgramResourceIndex exception error

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I have a simple yet complex problem. I am running the following code:

```
    OpenGL::PrintError(__FILE__, __LINE__);
GLuint raytracer = CompileRayTracer();
OpenGL::SetProgram(raytracer);
OpenGL::PrintError(__FILE__, __LINE__);

// Generate the buffer.
OpenGL::PrintError(__FILE__, __LINE__);
GLuint pixelbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &pixelbuffer);
OpenGL::PrintError(__FILE__, __LINE__);

glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, pixelbuffer);
OpenGL::PrintError(__FILE__, __LINE__);

glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, window.GetWidth() * window.GetHeight() * 4 * 3, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
OpenGL::PrintError(__FILE__, __LINE__);

glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, NULL);
OpenGL::PrintError(__FILE__, __LINE__);

GLuint index = glGetProgramResourceIndex(raytracer, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, "PixelBuffer");
OpenGL::PrintError(__FILE__, __LINE__);

glShaderStorageBlockBinding(raytracer, index, 1);
OpenGL::PrintError(__FILE__, __LINE__);
```

The contents of following variables are:

raytracer: 2

window.GetWidth() * window.GetHeight() * 4 * 3: 1228800

pixelbuffer: 1

Instead of some kind of OpenGL error display I get an exception error and my program breaks/chrashes on exactly that line.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

**EDIT:**

I found out that glGetProgramResourceIndex is null (the function pointer I guess), so I guess this has something to do with GLEW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was the following line:

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

Apperently some of the functions don't get loaded without this flag set.